# How to increment an array of object when ever an object is created?

Tags: java, arrays

In my project, I was given the class given below. It works like, whenever a Flat object is created the array `flats` is incremented by one flat object. My question is how can I increment this array every time a flat object is created.
Im really stuck on it. dont know where to start!

thx!

```
public class Block {

public Block() {
    super();
    flats = new Flat[0];
}



Flat[] flats;

class Flat {

    Room[] rooms;

    class Room {
        private int width;
        private int height;
        private int numWindow;

        public Room(int w, int h, int n) {
            super();
            this.width = w;
            this.height = h;
            this.numWindow = n;


        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return width + "/" + height + "/" + numWindow;
        }
    }

    public Flat() {
        super();
        rooms = new Room[0];


    }
}
}
```

Comment: Use `List<Flat>` instead.

Comment: use a factory design pattern

Comment: I can't. List is not allowed to use. I know using lists makes evrtg easy.

Comment: Could you please provide the method on how `Flat` objects are created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Flat` is `Block`'s inner class, therefore, the `flats` member variable is directly accessible from the `Flat` class.

As per the documentation:

> As with instance methods and variables, an inner class is associated with an instance of its enclosing class and has direct access to that object's methods and fields.

You can modify the `Flat` constructor like this:

```
public Flat() {
  super();
  rooms = new Room[0];

  // append the newly created flat into the flats array
  flats = Arrays.copyOf(flats, flats.length + 1);
  flats[flats.length - 1] = this;
}
```

This means the flats array will be copied for each new flat, which is arguably much less efficient than using an ArrayList.

While this works, I strongly recommend against having deeply nested class structures, and use a better dependency and ownership model. This is outside the scope of this question though.

Answer (score 0):

Can you sent this array to Flat's Constructor?

Code (based on your code):

```
public class Block {

    private Flat[] flats;

    public Block(Flat[] flats) {
        this.flats = flats;
    }

    public Flat[] getFlats() {
        return flats;
    }

    public void setFlats(Flat[] flats) {
        this.flats = flats;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(flats);
    }


    public class Flat {

        private String value;


        public Flat() {
            //init your Flat
            this.value = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            flats = Arrays.copyOf(flats, flats.length + 1);
            flats[flats.length - 1] = this;

        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return value;
        }
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Test");
        Block block = new Block(new Block.Flat[0]);
        block.new Flat();
        block.new Flat();

        System.out.println(block.toString());
    }

}
```

Output:
[b30c54dd-7e5d-46bc-81cf-18172e68337e, c22c4589-7563-4ada-a4eb-16226bd81f45]

Comment: Even if your reputation is to low to comment please do not post anything in that direction as an **answer** since it does not fulfill that purpose. You should rather focus on providing solutions to increase your rep,

Comment: Why vote down? My proposal will resolve this problem and now after update i added code sample.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50411116/1) is the reason I downvoted. Now you have edited your answer to be useful or at least an answer at all so I revoked my downvote. But still my original comment holds. Do not answer with a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Define flats array as static member of the class Block, and in the constructor of Flat push the newly created object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only count the objects, you don't need an array, you can use a static field called let's say NumOfObjects and increment it every time the constructor is created.
 However, if you wish to save the objects in an array I recommend you to use ArrayList  in this case (as static field in Flat class) [(documentation)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead of an array because of the fixed size of arrays in java, you'll have to create an array with fixed initial size and in the Flat constructor you should check if the array is full, you should create bigger array, copy the old one, and add the new object.
ArrayList takes care of all that instead of you.

Comment: I cant use arraylist, I am force to use the given array.

Comment: Then you have no other way than defining Flat as static with initial length let's say 10, and in the constructor of Flat you should check if the array is full, create a bigger array, copy the previous array, and add the new object, if not just add the new object.